# ios phonegap jquery $.post https

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, cordova, https

this way works:

```
$.post("http://10.60.1.157/tirulipa/cadastro", $("#frmCadastro").serialize(),function(data){
  if(data=="ok"){
   location.href="success.html"
  }else{
    alert("try again");
  }
});
```

but, this way no works ( just using https )

```
$.post("https://10.60.1.157/tirulipa/cadastro", $("#frmCadastro").serialize(),function(data){
  if(data=="ok"){
   location.href="success.html"
  }else{
    alert("try again");
  }
});
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Have you looked into Phonegap's [origin whitelisting](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)?

Comment: is released to all <access origin="*"/>

Comment: apparently states that the host has digital certificate with https, did a test on a host that possesses certificate and it seems it worked, sorry bad english